# XSLT Performance Issue

Tags: performance, xslt, saxon

The XSLT transformation is done through dot net code using API provided by Saxon. I am using Saxon 9 home edition api. The XSLT version is 2.0 and generates xml output. The input file size is 123 KB.

The XSLT adds attributes to the input XML file depending on certain scenarios. There are total 7 modes used in this XLST.  The value of attribute generated in one mode is used in another mode and hence multiple modes are used.

The output is correctly generated but it takes around 10 second to execute this XSLT. When same XSLT executed in 'Altova XMLSpy 2013', it took around 3-4 seconds.

Is there a way to further reduce this 10 second execution time? What could be the the cause for this much time for execution?

The XSLT is available at below link for download.

[XSLT Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNHtXPlfgCxOGIxazJzOGJ6cGM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You run 7 times through the full source file - that takes time. Also many when conditions, you might be better off defining templates with match conditions, less parsing required

Comment: Downvoting the question because the author has not returned to the site to see if it has been answered. Very irritating to spend time helping such people.

Answer (score 0):

Without having a source document to run this against (and therefore to make measurements) it's very hard to be definitive about where the inefficiencies are, but the most obvious at first glance is the weird testing of element names in patterns like:

```
match="*[name()='J' or name()='H' or name()='F' or name()='D' or name()='B' or name()='I' or name()='G' or name()='E' or name()='C' or name()='A' or name()='X' or name()='Y' or name()='O' or name()='K' or name()='L' or name()='M' or name()='N']
```

which in Saxon would be vastly more efficient if written the natural way as

```
match="J|H|F|D|B|I|G|E|C|A|X|Y|O|K|L|M|N"
```

It's also more likely to be correct that way, since comparing name() against a string is sensitive to the chosen prefix, and XSLT code really ought to work whatever namespace prefix the source document author has chosen.

The reason the latter is much more efficient is that Saxon organizes the source tree for rapid matching of elements by name (meaning namespace URI plus local name, excluding prefix). When you match by name in this way, the matching template rule can be found by a quick hash table lookup. If you use predicates that have to be evaluated by expanding the name (with prefix) as a string and comparing the string, not only does each comparison take longer, it can't be optimized with a hash lookup.

Comment: @Ambar, please be aware that it creates a very bad impression if you ask a question and then don't return to the site during the next week to see if there are any answers. We don't mind helping beginners, but we like to get some feedback for our efforts.

Comment: Please accept my sincere appologies for not replying your answer. I was not keeping well because of which couldn't replied to you. I have just implemented the changes you and stwissel suggested and now it takes 9 second for execution. Thanks a lot as your solution did improved the performance slightly. On the same line you have suggested I have modfied when condition to <xsl:when test="J|H|F|D|B|L|N"> but it gives wrong results. Is it because xslt execute match and when differently? Can this performance futher be improved?

Comment: There could be a difference due to namespaces: as I mentioned, it's hard to be definitive without access to a source document. You also need to be clear how you are measuring. If you're running from the command line, it could just be the time taken to load the Java VM.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The namespaces I am using are standard one.

Namespace used in source document is xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" and Namespace used in XSLT is xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform".

The xslt transformation is run through Dot NET code, using Dot NET API provided by Saxon. I am logging the time just before & after the xslt transformation through dot NET code and measuring the time for execution by calculating difference between them.

Document loading time is also logged separately and it is done in 3-4 miliseconds.

Comment: I am not sure whether I can share complete source document but I will try to share some part of it for your reference.